# Is it possible to hide the address bar and status bar in iOS 7 Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, fullscreen

Is it possible to hide the address bar and status bar in iOS 7?

In a landscape app I'm currently using the below code to do it for previous iOS versions and it work well even on IOS 7: when opening the page it goes full screen and stay so.

JS:

```javascript
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

HTML:

```html
<!-- For iOS web apps -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="AMC Walking Dead Story Sync">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

The fact is that on iOS 7 iPhone and iPad when tapping the bottom of the screen the address bar and status bar appear and the only way to get rid of it is to change the phone orientation and then change it back to the previous orientation. 
Is there anyway to avoid that manipulation?

Comment: Many answers on this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813476/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-address-bar-in-ios-7-safari

Comment: I don't see an answer on SO that's more working than the example code here. Hmm...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There is a method: `<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui”>`**
(*but it only works on iOS 7.1 - not on 7.0 nor 8.0*)

source: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614435/117030)

---

More details, from [iOS 7.1 beta 2 change log and release notes](http://bgr.com/2013/12/13/ios-7-1-beta-2-download-released/):

> **Safari Notes**
>
> A property, minimal-ui, has been added for the viewport meta tag key
>   that allows minimizing the top and bottom bars on the iPhone as the
>   page loads. While on a page using minimal-ui, tapping the top bar
>   brings the bars back. Tapping back in the content dismisses them
>   again.
>
> For example, use `<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=1024,
>   minimal-ui”>`.

---

**update:** I confirmed this method works in iOS 7.1 (official final release).
You can confirm for yourself with my [web app](http://hn.leftium.com), which uses the meta tag solution described above.

[image]

Comment: I'll wait for final release then to give a try, then I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmmmm.  I'm using 7.1.1 and your web app linked above does NOT hide the address bar etc when loaded.  Did they break it in 7.1.1?

Comment: This has been removed in iOS8.

Comment: Check this post about IOS8 implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this recommended `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`
It runs the site in standalone mode, which hides the UI. I'm unclear on how this compares to the minimal-ui solution above. I am under the impression this solution works for iOS versions before 7.1 as well.

Comment: This solution only work for web page you add as an app to your home screen.